# Different behaviour between MATLAB fmincon and scipy optimize minimize

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, mathematical-optimization, convex-optimization

I'm translating some code from MATLAB to python. This code simulate the behaviour of a model and I want to estimate parameters from it. The problem is that results obtained with python and with MATLAB are very different. I've tought it was related to the difference between the MATLAB's
`fmincon` and the python `scipy.optimize.minimize` function, but according to this tutorial that I've found on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwogAa1719M) the results are almost the same,so problems must be in my code but I can't find them.
I report a minimum example of my code

```
def cost_function(parameters, measured, t, x0, total_active):
    Tp = simulate(parameters, t, x0, total_active)
    measured = np.squeeze(measured)
    Tp = Tp[:,2]
    return (np.sum(np.power((np.divide(np.diff(measured), measured[1:])-np.divide(np.diff(Tp),Tp[1:])),2)))

def SIR_model(x, t, params, total_active):
    S0, _, R0 = x
    v, tau, I0 = params
    dSdt = - v * S0 * I0 / total_active(t)
    dIdt = v * S0 * I0 / total_active(t) - g * I0 - tau * I0
    dCdt = tau * I0
    return [dSdt, dIdt, dCdt]

def simulate(p, t, x0, total_active):
    T = np.zeros((len(t), 3))
    T[0, :] = x0
    for i in range(len(t) - 1):
        ts = [t[i], t[i + 1]]
        y = odeint(SIR_model, x0, ts, args=(p, total_active))
        x0 = y[-1]
        T[i + 1, :] = x0
    return T

def identify_model(data, initial_guess, t, N, total_active):
    # Set initial condition of the model
    x0 = []
    Q0 = data[0]
    x0.append(N - initial_guess['It0'] - Q0)
    x0.append(initial_guess['It0'])
    x0.append(Q0)
    It0 = initial_guess['It0']
    v = initial_guess['v']
    tau = initial_guess['tau']
    lim_sup = [v * 10, tau * 1.5, It0 * 1.3]
    lim_inf = [v * 0, tau * 0.9, It0 * 0.7]
    bounds = Bounds(lim_inf, lim_sup)
    options = {"maxiter": 1000,"ftol": 1e-08}
    return minimize(cost_function, np.asarray([initial_guess['v'], initial_guess['tau'],initial_guess['It0']]),args=(data, t, x0, total_active), bounds=bounds,options=options, tol=1e-08,method="SLSQP")['x']

data=[275.5,317.,457.33333333,646.,888.66666667,1236.66666667,1619.33333333,2077.33333333,2542.33333333]
times = [i for i in range(len(data))]
total_active_data=[59999725.,59999684.33333334,59999558.66666666,59999385.33333334,59999158.33333333,59998823.,59998474.66666666,59998053.33333333,59997652.66666666]
total_active = interp1d([i for i in range(len(total_active_data))], total_active_data, fill_value="extrapolate")
initial_guess = {"v": 0.97, "tau": 0.066, "It0": 100}
print(identify_model(data,initial_guess,times,60e6,total_active))
```

This snippet gives, as result, `[0.97099097,0.099,130.]`.
The (I hope so) equivalent MATLAB code is:

```
function [pars] = Identify_Model(data,initial_guess,lim_inf,lim_sup,times,N,total_active)

scalefac=100;

%Initialize the initial guess for each parameter
v=initial_guess.v;
It0=initial_guess.It0;
tau=initial_guess.tau;
g=0.07;

lim_inf(3)=lim_inf(3)/scalefac;
lim_sup(3)=lim_sup(3)/scalefac;

%Identify the model parameters
options=optimset('MaxIter',100,'TolFun',1e-6,'TolX',1e-6);
parmin=fmincon(@(pars) error_SIR(data,[pars(1),pars(2),g,scalefac*pars(3)],times,N,total_active),[v,tau,It0],[],[],[],[],lim_inf,lim_sup,[],options);
pars=num2cell([parmin(1:2),scalefac*parmin(3)]);

pars=[pars(1),pars(2),g,pars(3)];

end



function [costo]=error_SIR(data,pars,tempi,N,totale_attivi)

%Assign the parameters
pars=num2cell(pars);
[v,tau,g,I0]=pars{:};
%Simulate the model
Q0=data(1,1);
S0=N-I0-Q0;

[~,y]=ode45(@(t,x) SIR(t,x,v,tau,g,totale_attivi),tempi,[S0;I0;Q0]);
if length(tempi)==2
    y=[y(1,:);y(end,:)];
end

%Identify on the normalized data (Data/mean data)
costo=sum(((diff(sum(data,1))./sum(data(:,2:end),1))-(diff(sum(y(:,3),2))./sum(y(2:end,3),2))').^2);
end

function y=SIR(t,x,v,tau,g,total_active)
    y=zeros(3,1);
    y(1)=-v*x(1)*x(2)/total_active(t);           % S
    y(2)=v*x(1)*x(2)/total_active(t)-(tau+g)*x(2);   % I
    y(3)=tau*x(2);      % C
end

total_active_data=[59999725.,59999684.333,59999558.666,59999385.333,59999158.33,59998823.,59998474.66,59998053.333,59997652.66666666]
total_active  = @(t) interp1(1:9,total_active_data,t); 
initial_guess.It0=100;
initial_guess.v=0.97;
initial_guess.g=0.07;  
initial_guess.tau=0.066;
g=initial_guess.g;
It0=initial_guess.It0;
v=initial_guess.v;
tau=initial_guess.tau;
N=60e6
%Define the constrints for the identification
lim_sup=[v*10, tau*1.5, It0*1.3];
lim_inf=[v*0, tau*0.9, It0*0.7];
data=[275.5,317.,457.33333333,646.,888.66666667,1236.66666667,1619.33333333,2077.33333333,2542.33333333]

times=1:9;
%identify the model parameters
pars=Identify_Model(data,initial_guess,lim_inf,lim_sup,times,N,total_active)
```

And the result is     `{[0.643004812025865]}    {[0.0989999761533351]}    {[0.07]}    {[129.9999687237]}` (don't consider the value 0.07, it's fixed). I thought that the problem could linked to the fact that I want to minimize a non-convex function, and maybe `fmincon` is more powerful than the `scipy.optimize.minimize` function?

Comment: Well that always depends on the different algorithms behind these functions. MATLABs `fmincon` switches between different methods depending on the given inputs... if you want to use the exact same algorithms, I recommend to use the open-source library [NLopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which has apis to both, MATLAB and Python

Comment: Yeah, I've also thought it. But, the tutorial uses the SLSQP method of minimize and I've thought that it the corresponding MATLAB algorithm. Thanks for the library, do you suggest me to use it instead of scipy? Because the MATLAB code works very well, while the python one has very poor performance.

Comment: yes, to my experience, the algorithms are faster and more accurate than MATALB's native algorithms

Comment: Could I pass some extra paramereters to my objective function? The doc isn't clear on this point.

Comment: @IlMioFake Have you found any alternative to fmincon in python? I am facing the same issue...

Comment: @IlMioFake I've encountered the same question, migration from Matlab to Python. I use scipy.optimize.minimize with method "trust-constr". However, it converges slowly in Python and is no better than Matlab.