# what's the best alternative for fmincon ( matlab) in python?

Tags: matlab, scipy-optimize

I am facing the serious task of converting the Matlab code to python and I want to best implement the fmincon function in Matlab with the help of scipy.optimize in python but I'm not sure whether both the functions are working similarly.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Matlab and scipy work differently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790692/different-behaviour-between-matlab-fmincon-and-scipy-optimize-minimize .

Comment: @AskoldIlvento have you found the alternative for fmincon in python?

Comment: yes you can use scipy.optimize in python